# Documentation for Protractor test cases

Tags: javascript, documentation, protractor

I want to create a file with all the single describe and it of each spec.
For example: 
spec1:

```
describe("test new cars", () => {
it("check color", () => {
    //see if color is as expected
})
it("check model", () => {
    //check model
})
it("check motor", () => {
    //start car engine
})
})
```

In my file I only want to have:

```
spec1
test new cars
  check color
  check model
  check motor
```

I thought about writing a function which search for describe and it, take the line and remove the characters like (" {},) and use only the text. 
What do you think, is this a good idea to do it? 
If yes, can you give me tips how to write this function? 
Thanks for your help and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just *run all the tests* letting jasmine discover the tests and report them. Now, the question would be, which reporter to use. Since, this sounds like a one-off task, you may just as well do that with the [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter), redirect the test output to a file and clean it up afterwards:

```
protractor conf.js > output.txt
```

You can also use other reporters like `Junit XML Reporter` that would create an XML report which you can then parse. Though, I think this is a bit too much moving parts for this problem.

You may also write a simple custom [jasmine text reporter](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html) capturing suite and spec descriptions.

*Why doing it via a jasmine reporter?*

- you basically use the same infrastructure and tools you already have in place
- you would preserve hierarchy of the suites and specs

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I used fs.createWriteStream("**.md") and wrote all the names in this file.